# Why can't my image load on my tkinter window?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to add an image to my program but it's not working out, the code is correct as shown below, and the image i'm trying to open is in the same folder as the saved .py file.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Balance 0-21")
root.configure(width=400, height=200)
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/Balance 0-21/LogoCon.ico")

MasterCard = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("ten.png"))
MasterCardIMG = Label(image=MasterCard)
MasterCardIMG.grid(row=2, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Most of the time I get no errors but after messing around with the file directory i get a "file not found" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this after the MasterCardIMG Label creation (also for convention make the first letter lowercase as these aren't classes), I was having the same issue getting my images to show, I believe it has something to do with the label instance creation not being able to assign the image.

```
MasterCardIMG.image = MasterCard
```

(recommendation for convention)

```
masterCard = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("ten.png"))
masterCardIMG = Label(image=masterCard)
masterCardIMG.image = masterCard
masterCardIMG.grid(row=2, column=3)
```

Comment: That actually worked thanks so much for the suggestion!